# how to ensure the min space between two views in Relativelayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two TextViews in a RelativeLayout. One to the left and the other one to the right. Both of them shows a string which may become very long. I want to make a min space of 10dp between two TextViews and let the right one have ellipse if no enough space.

I have below layout definition which does not work. The right TextView may cover the first one if it is very lone.

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/left_one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:text=""/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/right_one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            />



</RelativeLayout>
```

The only way I can do is to set the max length to the right one. But this is not what I want because if the left one is short, i want the right one to be longer than the maxWidth.

And when I added "toRightOf" this work but the textView width becomes too long for a short string shown in it. That is not acceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `Add android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left_one` in right_one textview

remove `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` from right_one textview

replace `android:layout_marginRight="10dp"` by `android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"` in right_one textview

**For right_one textview to remain right if it is short replace right_one textview portion by**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left_one>
     <TextView
            android:id="@+id/right_one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: amazing, this works. And I did not remove alignParent for I need that. But it works. Thank you!

Comment: I found this solution has some side effect. the right one may become too long even if the text string is short, this is caused by adding "toRightOf"

Comment: have you tried removing android:layout_alignParentRight="true"?

Comment: I cannot remove that for I need it to be at that position

Comment: Thanks I also solve it by this! This is the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right_one"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
```

to your `left_one` `TextView`.

Comment: this does not work, the right one still cover the left one

Comment: Can you post your RelativeLayout attributes?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="horizontal" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:weightSum="1">


   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/left_one"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
       android:gravity="bottom"
       android:layout_weight="0.3"
       android:text="Left text "/>

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/right_one"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:maxLines="1"
       android:ellipsize="end"
       android:layout_weight="0.7"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
       android:text="edkjfcnrdskjvkjrdfvsxsdcndsjkvnjksdnvkj 
        sdjkvbksdbvkj zskjvn jsdnbjkvfdbde"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: RelativeLayout is much better than LinearLayout with weightSum. Layout with weightSum takes long time and complexity while execution.

Comment: But for some reason I need to use RelativeLayout. Is it possible to do this in RelativeLayout?

Comment: put this inside relative layout